# Migration to NextJS: How can I solve this Hydration error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, migration, hydration

I'm really getting desperate right now, trying to solve this problem for two weeks now and still don't know what to do.

I have a React app that I want to migrate to NextJS to get better performance and SEO benefits. I am gradually adding the components to the app to get everything working.

After fixing some stuff, I now get a hydration error and don't know why, nor what part of the code I could show you.

> Unhandled Runtime Error - Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

I've tried to narrow it down to a single component, but every time I think I've found it, it slips through my fingers and then the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Right now this is happening: In my component Contact.js I only have this inside:

```
import React from 'react';

const Contact = () => {

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>test</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contact;
```

but if I just write `test` instead of `<h2>test<h2/>`, the error goes away! By the way, it doesn't matter if it's `h2`, `p`, or `div`.

Here is my **index.js**:

```
import React, { Fragment, Suspense } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Loading from '../components/shared/Loading';

const AboutMe = dynamic(() => import('../components/AboutMe'), {suspense: true});
const Contact = dynamic(() => import('../components/Contact'), {suspense: true});

function App() {


  return (
    <Fragment>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <AboutMe/>
            <Contact/>
        </Suspense>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**AboutMe.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Tag from './Tag';

const AboutMe = () => {


  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>title</h2>
                <h3>subtitle</h3>

                <div>
                    text
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Tag href="/tag1">tag1</Tag>
                    <Tag href="/tag2">tag2</Tag>
                    <Tag href="/tag3">tag3</Tag>
                    <Tag href="/tag4">tag4</Tag>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>test2</div>
            </div>
        

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AboutMe;
```

**Tag.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import Link from 'next/link';

function Tag(props) {
    const { ref, inView } = useInView({
        threshold: .5,
        triggerOnce: true
      });

  return (
    <Link href={props.href} passHref>
      <a>
        {props.children}
      </a>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Tag;
```

**Loading.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function Loading() {
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Loading;
```

I broke down my app as best I could to make it clearer, and so the error still shows up. I can delete various places and the error disappears - but then I still don't know what the problem is because it doesn't make sense to me (e.g. just what problem does it have with my h2 tag???)!

Am I making any mistakes with `dynamic` or `Suspense`? Or is it the `react-intersection-observer` with `useInView` that I need for my micro animations? I also checked every part in my app to make sure it is closed properly. Or am I still missing something there?

I really hope for your swarm intelligence! Surely it's something stupidly simple, which is why I can't get it googled

Comment: Remove the dynamic imports, suspense, loading, `useInView`, and animation libraries. Then add them back one at a time to isolate your error.  i.e., remove both `AboutMe` and `Comment` components, then add them back one at a time without dynamic import. Then add the dynamic import w/o options - then add the options. You may need to set `ssr:false` in your dynamic import but then you're just hydrating client-side defeating the purpose of migrating.

Comment: Thank you, @SeanW, it all works now that I started from scratch adding everything without the dynamic and suspense stuff! Now I just need to find out how to use them in Next properly 